# Why people use the accept header with all media types

Tags: http, post, get

Why people use

```
"Accept: */*\r\n"
```

in HTTP requests? As far as I can see in the reference, it is the default value of this header:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the
>   client accepts all media types

Answer (score 1):

Because some buggy servers fail in absence of "Accept".